# Understanding block diagrams

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

> If I have block diagram with input $X(s)$ that goes to a block with $\frac{1}{s + 2}$ in it and then by way of $w(s)$ to a block with $s$ in it, and finally to the output $Y(s)$, how do I find the response $w(t)$ given that $x(t) = \delta(t)$.

[image: block diagram]

---

Since $x(t)$ is defined as above, $X(s) = 1$. So can I write $w(s) = \frac{X(s)}{s + 2}=\frac{1}{s + 2}$? Therefore, $w(t) = e^{-2t}$.

---

Well this can't be entirely correct since it says to find $y(t)$ by differentiating $w(t)$. We know that $Y(s) = \frac{s}{s + 2} = 1 - \frac{2}{s + 2}$
So
$$
y(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1 - 2/(s + 2))e^{st}ds = \delta(t) -2e^{-2t}
$$
If we differentiate $w(t)$ obtained above, we don't pick up the $\delta(t)$.

Comment: Is it because $w(t)$ should be $e^{-2t}u(t)$, and $y(t)$ should be $\delta(t) - 2e^{-2t}u(t)$?

Comment: @peterwhy why is there $u(t)$ and how does differentiating $u(t)$ pick up a delta funciton?

Comment: $u(t)$ is Heaviside step function, so its derivative is $\delta(t)$.

Comment: @obareey I don't understand why $w(t) = e^{-2t}u(t)$ instead of just $e^{-2t}$.

Comment: Because $\mathcal{L}\{e^{-2t} u(t)\} = \frac{1}{s+2}$. $\mathcal{L}\{e^{-2t}\}$ doesn't converge for bilateral Laplace transformation.

Comment: @obareey do you want to post an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-2t} u(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2t} u(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_{0}^\infty e^{-2t} e^{-st} dt = \frac{1}{s+2}$$

$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-2t}\}$ doesn't converge for bilateral Laplace transformation.